# Don't display message text if field is empty in phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am working on a form using phpmailer. Here is the basic expression to display one of the fields:

```
 $f_request = isset($_POST['f_request']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_request']): "";

$msgBody .= "

■Text1

$f_request

"
```

How can I display "■Text1", only if $f_request is not empty?

Sorry, my PHP knowledge is really low, so I don't know the correct grammar to build an `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already checking **[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)**, but you'll additionally probably want to confirm it's not empty with **[`!empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)**. You don't need to make use of `$f_request` at all, as your check can be against the `$_POST` itself. You can also conditionally append it to the `$msgBody` if it's set, as can be seen in the following:

```
$msgBody = "";
if (isset($_POST['f_request']) && !empty($_POST['f_request'])) {
    $msgBody .= "■Text1" . $_POST['f_request'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, But I dont understand how this expression can print something inside the message body.

Comment: This doesn't. You haven't actually sent *anything* to the message body yet; you've only stored data inside a local variable (`$msgBody`). **After** this, you send the processed `$msgBody` to PHPMailer to actually append its contents to the body (with something like `$mail  = new PHPMailer(); $mail->Body = $msgBody;`).

Comment: As this is the last field of many other fields, how can it be displayed (or not) in the last position of the message body?

Comment: Simply append content (or variables) into one variable (`$msgBody`), and then append that variable into the message body itself (see my above comment).  Basically just ensure that `$msgBody` is whatever you want the body content to be **before** adding it to the 'email' itself with `$mail->Body = $msgBody;`.